# Ошибка в строке с break (Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement)

Tags: javascript

```
var answer = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
var playerNum = 1;

while(true) {
  var userAnswer = prompt("Игрок " + playerNum + ": Введите число от 0 до 100, для выхода нажмите q");
  if (userAnswer == "q")
    break;
  }
  userAnswer = parseInt(userAnswer);

  if (userAnswer > answer) {
      alert("Ваше число слишком большое!");
  } else if (userAnswer < answer) {
      alert("Ваше число слишком мало!");
  } else if (userAnswer == answer) {
      alert ("Вы угадали!" + playerNum);
      break; // ОШИБКА ТУТ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  } else {
      alert ("Необходимо вести число!");
      continue;
  }

  if (playerNum == 1) {
      playerNum == 2;
  } else {
    playerNum == 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оператор `break` может использовать **только внутри** цикла.

Если отформатировать твой код, то будет видно, что второй break уже не в цикле `while`, именно поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Скорее всего не хватает открывающей скобки `{` в строке

```
if (userAnswer == "q")
```

Либо убрать закрывающую `}` после первого break

```
if (userAnswer == "q")
    break;
}
```

Comment: да точно спасибо, забыл закрыть в break} и еще плюс цикл while забыл закрыть} хотя все проверял эхх.