# Illegal break statement

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
myNodes.forEach(function(node, j, node_arr) {   
                                    if((countDescription < 300)&&(node.nodeName=="IMG")){
                                        shortAnswer = shortAnswer+node.outerHTML;
                                    }else if(countDescription < 300){
                                        shortAnswer = shortAnswer+node.innerText.substr(0, 300-countDescription);
                                    }else{
                                        //break; //Почему здесь ошибка?
                                    }
                                });
```

Собственно текст ошибки:

> SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Я [читал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657963/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81-break-uncaught-syntaxerror-illegal-break-statement) что такая ошибка может быть если потерял "{" либо "}", но тут всё вроде правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что команда `break;` не находится внутри цикла `for` или `while`или внутри `switch/case`.

```
myNodes.some(function(node) {
  if ((countDescription < 300) && (node.nodeName == "IMG")) {
    shortAnswer = shortAnswer + node.outerHTML;
  } else if (countDescription < 300) {
    shortAnswer = shortAnswer + node.innerText.substr(0, 300 - countDescription);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```